# Raw textures don't work at all! OpenGL

Tags: c++, file, opengl, textures

Here is my load code:

```
GLuint Utils::loadTextureRAW(const char *filename, int width, int height) {
GLuint texture;
char *data;
fstream file(filename, ios::binary | ios::in);
if (!file.good())
    return 0;

// allocate buffer
data = static_cast<char*>(malloc(width * height * 4));

// read texture data
file.read(data, width * height * 4);

file.close();

int i;
for (i = 0; i < width * height * 4; ++i) {
    cout << static_cast<int>(data[i]) << "|";
}

// allocate a texture name
glGenTextures(1, &texture);

// select our current texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_DECAL);

// when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
// when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// texture should tile
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

// build our texture mipmaps
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

// free buffer
delete data;

return texture; }
```

Here is my using code:

```
int Object::redraw() {
const float sizex = 0.5f;
const float sizey = 0.5f;
const float sizez = 0.5f;

glTranslatef(-px, -py, -pz);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPushMatrix();

//поворачиваем будущий объект объект
//rotating next object
glRotatef(rx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(ry, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(rz, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

//рисуем
//drawing
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// FRONT
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, -sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex , 0.0f);
glVertex3f(sizex, -sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizey);
glVertex3f(-sizex, sizey, sizez);
// BACK
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, -sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, -sizey, -sizez);
// LEFT
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, -sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, sizey);
glVertex3f(-sizex, sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizey);
glVertex3f(-sizex, -sizey, -sizez);
// RIGHT
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(sizex, -sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(sizex, sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, -sizey, sizez);
// TOP
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(sizex, sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizey);
glVertex3f(-sizex, sizey, -sizez);
// BOTTOM
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, -sizey, sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-sizex, -sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(sizex, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, -sizey, -sizez);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, sizey);
glVertex3f(sizex, -sizey, sizez);

glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); }
```

Here is texture:

```
000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

EDITED:
Detected one other problem - for (i = 0; i < width * height * 4; ++i) outputs this:

```
1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|5|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-128|63|59|20|1|0|0|0|64|9|-108|2|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-64|27|-78|0|2|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-128|63|0|0|-128|63|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-98|70|41|-127|-1|127|0|0|99|-51|56|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|-16|117|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-104|123|115|0|1|0|0|0|0|-16|117|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|64|0|-97|65|0|0|0|0|64|7|-86|34|0|0|0|0|-80|-15|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-128|117|9|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-80|52|-108|2|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-128|-14|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-32|-15|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|32|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|32|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|64|7|0|0|0|0|0|0|-96|110|118|0|1|0|0|0|64|7|0|0|0|0|0|0|-96|110|118|0|1|0|0|0|32|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|80|-13|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-128|47|8|0|2|0|0|0|-32|-15|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|32|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-128|-14|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|32|-12|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|64|7|-86|34|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-16|28|-108|2|1|0|0|0|2|2|-17|-66|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|3|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|96|0|-97|65|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|42|0|0|0|-80|52|-108|2|1|0|0|0|-80|-10|-65|95|0|1|0|0|64|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|-64|45|-63|95|-1|127|0|0|-48|-13|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|3|0|0|0|-1|127|0|0|112|-12|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|73|86|-55|2|1|0|0|0|0|116|17|0|1|0|0|0|105|86|-55|2|1|0|0|0|-72|91|-55|2|1|0|0|0|48|-12|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|6|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|73|86|-55|2|1|0|0|0|-96|-12|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|16|0|0|0|-1|127|0|0|73|86|-55|2|1|0|0|0|5|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-96|-10|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|64|-13|119|0|1|0|0|0|0|-120|-127|1|1|0|0|0|19|-74|36|92|32|-66|35|74|-96|110|118|0|1|0|0|0|45|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-112|-11|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|112|-9|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-64|-43|29|112|-1|127|0|0|-80|-10|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-128|-11|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-41|10|45|-127|-1|127|0|0|-78|-10|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-112|-15|119|0|42|0|0|0|8|2|-1|-1|1|0|0|0|-80|-10|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|44|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|-128|-15|119|0|1|0|0|0|-16|-11|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|0|48|111|0|1|0|0|0|0|-16|117|0|1|0|0|0|0|-16|117|0|1|0|0|0|-16|-11|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|96|120|-108|2|1|0|0|0|16|-12|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|48|-12|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|16|-128|-108|2|1|0|0|0|0|48|111|0|1|0|0|0|16|-114|114|0|1|0|0|0|64|-10|-65|95|-1|127|0|0|-19|111|8|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|4|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|-89|-85|-86|50|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

But if I correctly understand half of it must be zeros and half must be 255. WTF or I'm doing something wrong?

EDITED:
Tried to do this:

```
data[0] = 0;
data[1] = 0;
data[2] = 0;
data[3] = 255;
data[4] = 0;
data[5] = 0;
data[6] = 0;
data[7] = 255;
data[8] = 0;
data[9] = 0;
data[10] = 0;
data[11] = 255;
data[12] = 0;
data[13] = 0;
data[14] = 0;
data[15] = 255;
```

And texture is all black(http://cl.ly/7KJd), changed zeros to 255 and texure is white. So the problem is in file loading!

### ******************

### PROBLEM WAS SOLVED!

---

Comment: What's the problem?  I just see code?!!!!

Comment: The problem is http://cl.ly/7Kce but as you see THE TEXTURE IS BLACK! Sorry I forgot to write my problem :)

Comment: It looks kind of white to me...

Comment: I know, I meant that texture MUST be black. But it's white! WTF? One correction: it must be BLACK and WHITE(half of block is black and half is white).

Comment: First of all: DON'T USE `delete` ON `malloc` ALLOCATED MEMORY! Use either `malloc/free` or `new/delete` but don't mix them! I don't think that causes your problem, but it is definitely an error. In this case you're quite lucky it worked (because everyting is simple types, I suppose).

Comment: The calls to `glTexParameteri` with `GL_DECAL` as filtering mode are complete rubbish, but as you make the right calls in the next lines, this shouldn't cause your problem. And although, the `glTexParameterf` calls should work, I would replace them with `glTexParameteri`, as you are really calling them with integer constants.

Comment: I think problem with my texture file loading, because when I run my program twice a got deferent values for data array! Whats I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenGL, white textures show up when the texture is incomplete or in error.

Most of the time, it's related to missing mipmaps, but as you use `gluBuild2DMipmaps` it may not be directly related.

You should try to call `glGetError` to try to narrow down your problem : as mentionned in the comments, you make a lot of improper GL calls in the code you posted.

Comment: Tried it. glGetError() returns me 1280. What it means?

Comment: You should update your question and your code to reflect the problem you're really having, it's hard to follow you.

Comment: @HiTECNOLOGYs Check this code to check what error strings represents your error code: GLenum errCode;string errString;errCode = glGetError();if (errCode != GL_NO_ERROR){ errString = gluErrorString(errCode);}

Comment: Thanks! glGetError() helped me.